# Pasring JSON data using Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

This is my code for getting the atribute name and value assosiated with it fromstring json data .The code is getting executed without errror but i am getting the result as null.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

  public class A18 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{
String[] out2;
String out,out1= null;
try{
    URL a=new URL("URL");
    HttpURLConnection b=(HttpURLConnection) a.openConnection();
    b.setRequestMethod("GET");
    b.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    BufferedReader c=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(b.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();



while((out=c.readLine())!=null)
 {
    sb.append(out);
 out1=sb.toString();
 }

c.close();
b.disconnect();


 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    String id = obj.toJSONString("collection");
    String error = obj.toJSONString("links");
 }
        catch (Exception e)
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }   

    }}
```

Comment: Please show us the import statements as they seem to be important.

Comment: Check your imports. You seem to be using two JSON parsing libraries together, and to have imported the wrong `JSONObject`.

Comment: I have solved that thanks but i am getting another error

Comment: which error now you are getting ? also show import statement and mention library which you are using.

Answer (score -1):

In your imports code above all of this you're having `import org.json.JSONObject`, changing that to `import org.json.simple.JSONObject` should help.

Most probably you'll have other imports of `org.json.x` you'll have to change to `org.json.simple.x`.