# Getting nested JSON data from string JSON data

Tags: java, arrays, json, nested

I am trying to get nested JSON data from string JSON data using JSONObject and JSONArray. The code is compiling without any error but the result is coming **Null** rather than the string associated. If there is any alternate way to nest JSON string please suggest.

My code:

```
  import java.io.*;
  import java.net.*
  import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
  import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

  public class A4 {
   public static void main(String[] args){
    String out,out1= null;
    try{
        URL a=new URL("URL");
        HttpURLConnection b=(HttpURLConnection) a.openConnection();
        b.setRequestMethod("GET");
        b.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        BufferedReader c=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(b.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        while((out=c.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(out);
            out1=sb.toString();
            }

       c.close();
       b.disconnect();
    }catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       return;
    }
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try{
        Object obj = parser.parse(out1);
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            String name = (String) jsonObject.get("Name");
        System.out.println(name);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
 }
```

Comment: How is this any different from the question you asked an hour ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40648754/pasring-json-data-using-java

Comment: Its a different code

Comment: Post your complete stack trace and also a sample of your json file

Comment: the line of `out1=sb.toString()` is the same  though. That's the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

try the below code i think it should work for you:

```
while((out=c.readLine())!=null){
    sb=sb.append(out);
}
out1=sb.toString();
```

please let me know whether it's working for you or not?

Comment: tat part of the code has no problem .The problem is with this part of the code using which i need to create a nested json.                                                 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try{
        Object obj = parser.parse(out1);
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            String name = (String) jsonObject.get("Name");
        System.out.println(name);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using  JSONParser to get the JSONObject you can directly use the following code

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(out1)
```